# Tell Python to use alternative library

Tags: python, libraries, opencv

I am trying to use an alternative version of opencv (3.0) in my Python scripts. I compiled and installed this version to my home directory, and now I am trying to tell Python to use it. I have the standard opencv version (2.4.8) installed with apt-get.

My problem is that python always imports the 2.4.8 version, even when I add the dist-packages of version 3.0 at the beginning or at the end of PYTHONPATH. Deleting opencv 2.4.8 is no option.

How could I do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV is a C library with python bindings rather than a python one, you need to tell the C environment to look in the correct library path, as well as the python one. To do that, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Assuming the OpenCV `.so` file is (say) `$HOME/opencv-3.0/lib/libopencv.so.3`, you do the following:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/opencv-3.0/lib PYTHONPATH=(...whatever...) python <script>
```

Comment: Do you know in which order the libraries are checked? /usr/lib is not part of LD_LIBRARY_PATH and so I think it is always checked before going to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which would lead to using the older opencv version.

Comment: nevermind, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is checked first.